# Font Changes on different android versions

Tags: android, fonts, textview, version

i've used sp instead of dp for textsize on a textview,my device(7 inch) android version is 4.1.1 but it's Font changes and got larger on a device with same inch but Android 3.2.how can i prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently from Screen size, different devices can have different screen resolutions, which gives different screen densities. As such you should always work in device independent pixels, so your best bet is to switch from SP to DP for your font sizes. Each device will handle SP differently.

The system will automatically scale based it's resolution.

More about pixel density and screen resolutions on Android and what it means for the developer found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

**Edit:** (from comments below)

You can add your own font the the project by placing it in your assets folder and calling

`Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "myFont.ttf");`

followed by

```
TextView.setTypeface(tf ,1);
```

Comment: dp and sp doesn't make difference in both devices(both are samsung 7 inches) but one of them has android 4.1.1 and the other has android 3.2 and in device that has android 3.2 fonts got larger

Comment: With both being the same type of device, the difference is in the operating systems, Android 4.0 introduced a new Font as default, called Roboto. This and tweaks to the internal workings of the operating system will be the source of your issue

Comment: so how can i solve the issue and make the fonts same in both?

Comment: you can add your own font the the project by placing it in your assets folder and calling Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "myFont.ttf"); followed by TextView.setTypeface(tf ,1); or you can be less concerned about the 3.2 device as it is upgradable to 4.0